# selenium invalid element state: Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated

Tags: selenium

I have this issue with selenium; I cannot find i textinput : it always raises this exeception:

```
Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated
```

in this line:

```
Driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00")).Clear();
```

I try to put waiting like this:

```
Waiting.Until(driver =>(By.Id("ctl00")));
```

and

```
Waiting.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.Id("ctl00")));
```

but no luck.

Comment: I HATE THIS ERROR MESSAGE. why can't the error message just tell me what the selector was?!?!?!?!?! spending my WHOLE LIFE FINDING DUMB BUGS LIKE THIS

Answer (score 16):

If the exception gets thrown on `Clear()`, 
the element is most likely present on the page and the input in a `readonly` state.

Comment: If you dont mind getting dirty you can execute javascript/jquery directly and look for your element then manipulate...however, if the application sets the input to readonly, it may be helpful to reconsider and ask why you are attempting to clear out a readonly input.

Comment: I had this issue on a Clear(), but after some investigation it turned out that the issue was that there were two elements sharing a class.  The logic was grabbing the one that was not visible on screen.  Switched them both to IDs and everything worked.

Answer (score 5):

Try to validate XPath first as might be that targeting more than one element.
Due to this, element not currently interactable and may not be manipulated.

I faced same issue and found solution with above as my XPath was locating multiple element which exists on DOM but not page.

Correct the element XPath, error will resolve automatically with adding webdriver wait.

Answer (score 4):

I hit the same error, was also a bit confused, but resolved it using the below wait condition.  The `elementToBeClickable` condition checks that the element is both visible and enabled. Perhaps visibility is enough, but Selenium throws an explicit `ElementNotVisibleException`, so I'm not sure why I wouldn't get that... 
 Anyways, I opted to use a more robust wait condition, and it has worked well for me.

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("myElementId"))).clear();
```

Comment: same code in python; WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "id_content"))) from https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp

Answer (score 3):

It is due to element not visible so apply more wait while performing the action or you can use hardcoded sleep cause sometimes webdriver's wait doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

This happens sometimes when element is not visible. It would happen even when element is visible also. 
Try using with different tags like xpath or etc.

You can check the element status using below script

```
driver.findElement(By.className("")).isEnabled()
```

Comment: this is a great answer, but i'm curious how you determined which element it was that was not interactable? the error message is so devoid of information.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to perform `.clear()` on a `WebElement`, which is not an `input` tag. For example, if you try to do clear on a `Span` `WebElement`, You will get `Selenium Invalid Element State` error.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

`Waiting.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.Id("ctl00")));` should work.

Set break point at `Waiting.Until()` line and input `$$("#ctl00")` in Chrome console to check if the element is existing.

Answer (score 0):

Make the driver to wait until an element is visible.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If waiting for `visibilityOf()`, `elementToBeClickable()`, `element.isEnabled()` doesn't do the trick, try to look at the attributes of your element.

It may have some attributes responsible for read only state, in my case this was *aria-readonly* and *aria-disabled*, Hence I created custom wait like this:

```
webDriverWait.until(webDriver -> webElement.getAttribute("aria-readonly").equals("false") && webElement.getAttribute("aria-disabled").equals("false"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this you will not get this error(might be scroll is not working here so use keypad TAB to move on, my problem got resolved by this)

```
     Actions act = new Actions(driver);

       act.sendKeys(Keys.TAB).build().perform();
       act.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN).build().perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be asking an element with the same attribute like duplicate id, name etc.
I My case i was entering password in confirm password TextBox whose Id was "confirmPassword" but the same Id is used for the "Confirm Password" label for that TextBox.

So selenium was trying to perform sendKeys on the label instead of TextBox so getting "InvalidElementStateException", After that i changed the xpath and it worked.

So when you get "InvalidElementStateException" you should first check whether there are any duplicate element available with the xpath you have generated, and that not-interactive element could be a Button, Label or disabled element that causes the exception occurred.

Answer (score 0):

I was clicking on a div element or label to element to clear the text in input tag. Changed my xpath to input tag and then I did not received any exception and the test was clear.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).